# How to aggregate database entries?

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate

I'm writing a tool that shows the price (and the price change) of several markets. The prices get polled from a webservice every second and get stored in a mysql5 database like this:

table_market:

PK:timestamp | base_currency | quote_currency | price

This means for 10 markets I have 600 entries after one minute, which is pretty much :/.

So my idea is to aggregate the data: I want to store the price each second for the last 5 minutes. For older entries I want to aggregate the data so 5 minutes are only one row. For entries that are older than 30 minutes I want to aggregate them too..

So far I imagined to create one table for each market but that would only split the things up :( So my question is: Has any one an idea for a good data-model that fit my needs? Would be awesome <3

Best regards,

realTaste :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of prices you are referring to, it might be better to only store the data if it is changed. So in stead of storing it every second, store it only if it differs from the last price.